# Connecting remote Oracle DB using pro*c

Tags: c, oracle, oracle-call-interface, oracle-pro-c

I want to connect to remote oracle DB using pro*c in C program.
I am able to connect to the DB using oracle sql developer using,

```
UserId : ABCD
Password: abcd
HostIP(Name): 123.45.67.890 (Qwerty)
Service Name: Asd03
```

Also Can someone share references on how to do it ?

I don't want to install oracle in my system (due to space constraints), Can it be done using ***oracle instant-client modules***?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this can be done using the instant client.
To make debugging your installation easier I advice to also install the sqlplus client.

First get your sqlplus client connected. (This will learn you how to set ORACLE_HOME and path)

Next, with the setting from step 1, try to connect your pro*c client.

Comment: Thanks @ik_zelf for the reply.
I am able to connect to DB server using sqlPlus. Just extracted the zipped folder to C:/instant_client directory 
and adding this directory to my path variable.
I can connect to remote DB using easy connect syntax of SQL plus.

However I don't know how can I use instant client precompiler files. Even after adding the path of "proc" application, when I run 
" proc file1.pc" or simply "proc"
it shows "proc" is not recognized. Any references on how to use instant client proc compiler?

Comment: Maybe here is something useful https://oradim.blogspot.com/2009/09/getting-started-with-oracle-proc-on.html To me it looks like your windows environment is not completely OK. Otherwise proc would have been found,

Comment: Thanks ik_zelf, I am following the same blog :).
I got the issue resolved by restarting the PC.